# SQL Looking up the missing combinations in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following information:

```
GroupId  GroupName   PersonId
1        'Inactive'  1
2        'Inactive'  2
3        'Inactive'  3
```

I would like to build a new table with the missing persons by group like:

```
GroupId  GroupName   PersonId
1        'Inactive'  2
1        'Inactive'  3
2        'Inactive'  1
2        'Inactive'  3
3        'Inactive'  1
3        'Inactive'  2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `CROSS JOIN` in  [***this manner***](https://rextester.com/BQV56574):

```
with t( GroupId ,  GroupName, PersonId ) as
(
 select 1, 'Inactive', 1 union all
 select 2, 'Inactive', 2 union all
 select 3, 'Inactive', 3
)
select t1.GroupId ,  t1.GroupName, t2.PersonId 
  from t t1 cross join t t2
 where t1.GroupId != t2.PersonId;

GroupId GroupName   PersonId
   1    Inactive       2
   1    Inactive       3
   2    Inactive       1
   2    Inactive       3
   3    Inactive       1
   3    Inactive       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cross join` to get all combinations.  Then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select g.groupId, gn.groupName, p.personId
from (select distinct groupId from t) g cross join
     (select distinct groupName from t) gn cross join
     (select distinct PersonId from t) p left join
     t
     on t.groupId = g.groupid and
        t.groupName = gn.groupName and
        t.personId = p.personId
where t.groupId is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CROSS JOIN` and `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT t1.GroupId, t2.GroupName, t3.PersonId FROM tab t1, tab t2, tab t3
EXCEPT
SELECT GroupId, GroupName, PersonId FROM tab;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bd86397f21d7531b3573f4970f99e887)**